# Google Meet Audit Logs - IP of Unverified User

Tags: google-admin-sdk

is there a way to retrieve the ip addresses of unverified accounts joining a Google Meet session from the audit logs? Right now, the usernames of these unverified accounts are shown but not their ip addresses.[Screenshot of audit log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYtEO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### As the name says, the Google Admin SDK can create reports for admins of a certain domain

- Those reports contain activity of the domain users
- The reports will not give you the IP address of Non-Domain users, this is intended behavior
- If a user is `Unverified` - that is not signed in with his Google account, there is no way to know either he is a domain user or not

**Summary:**

- If you want to know your users' IP addresses, do not allow them to join the meeting unverified
- If you invite non-domain users to join a meeting, you cannot track their IPs with the Admin API

Comment: Is there any other way to find ip address of users who are connecting based on their email address??